# Vuex mutation inside array of objects after backend update saves

Tags: vuejs2, state, vuex, mutation, vuex-modules

I have an array of objects. When my api executes the update method and saves, I'm am broadcasting an event through laravel-echo-server and attempting to mutate state with the update object. I'm trying for real-time updates. Everything but the actual mutation is going according to plan. Here is the beginning of it:

```
updateExample (state, example) {
  state.examples.map(e => {
    if (e.id === example.id) {
      // entirely replace the old object with the new
    }
    return false
  })
},
```

What is an ideal way to do this? I could also pop the old object out of the array and push a new one, but that seems wonky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out:

```
updateExample (state, example) {
  let index = state.examples.findIndex(e => e.id === example.id)
  if (index !== -1) {
    state.examples[index] = new Example(example)
    return
  }
  state.examples.push(new Example(example))
}
```

Thanks for looking at it!